# Android Looper error

Tags: android

When i run my app a service starts in the background and it runs till this  part.But after it shows "Before Looper" in Logcat file some error will be generated saying only one looper may be created per thread.After this app will be stopped saying unfortunately stopped.Not getting what to do.Any help would be really appreciated.thanks in advance.

private void takePic() {

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.d("MyTag",
                        "Inside take pic");

                Looper.prepare();

                Capture capture = new Capture(
                        MyServiceOne.this.getBaseContext());
                Capture.takePic(MyServiceOne.this);
                Log.d("MyTag",
                        "before looper");
                Looper.loop();

                Log.d("MyTag",
                        "after looper");



            }
        }).start();

}
```

What should i do in order to successfully call the public method takePic which is in Capture class.

Comment: I see Looper, but i don't see any way it is used. Describe, where you got `Capture` class, and what you trying to accomplish with code above.

Comment: And *why* is it being used?  If it was added in response to the infamous message about not having called Looper.prepare() then this is probably mistaken.

Comment: In Capture class there are methods which will take pics and store them on SD card. takePic method will look like this..  public void takePic(ICapture obj){ }.

Comment: I got this error when i removed looper and ran code.AndroidRuntime(27455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()